# The type or namespace name 'ExtendedControls' does not exist in the namespace 'CMS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, kentico

We have upgraded to Kentico 10 version and we have custom search page from A-Z when we click particular alphabet it showing the error. please suggest me how to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

For the next time try to use [API changes tool](https://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/api-changes/kentico-10?page=1&signature=extendedcontrols&type=class) first.